# Highcharts display series.name on X Axis

Tags: javascript, svg, charts, highcharts

I'm trying to display each series name on X-Axis
http://jsfiddle.net/Jr79Y/9/
[image]

```
series: [{
            name: 'Test',
            data: [20]
        }, {
            name: 'Test',
            data: [20]
        }, {
            name: 'Test',
            data: [40]
        }]
```

Does somebody knows how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a much simpler solution than anything I'm seeing for answers so far:

```
 xAxis: {
            categories:[]
        }
```

.

```
series: [{
            data: [{name:'Test 1',y:20,color:'red'},
                   {name:'Test 2',y:20,color:'blue'},
                   {name:'Test 3',y:40,color:'green'}]
        }]
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/Jr79Y/37/

Although unless you have a *really* good reason for having each bar be a different color, it usually just adds unnecessary visual clutter and you're better off leaving them a single color.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
xAxis: {
  categories: ['Test', 'Test', 'Test'],
  title: {
    text: null,
  }
},
```

And in series part:

```
series: [{
     name: 'Values',
     data: [20,20,40]
},]
```

[Reference](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-basic).

**EDITED:**

You are using three group so you need to modify your data format. If you want the different color then try this:

```
series: [{
         name: 'Values',
         data: [20,0,0]
    },
{
         name: 'Values',
         data: [0,20,0]
    },
{
         name: 'Values',
         data: [0,0,40]
    },]
```

Comment: @Hiero I am not understanding. can you clarify plz.

Comment: I want to keep this series: [{
            name: 'Test',
            data: [20]
        }, {
            name: 'Test',
            data: [20]
        }, {
            name: 'Test',
            data: [40]
        }]

Comment: Because thats how I can change colors to each bar

Comment: There are several ways to change the color for each bar. Most of the time, it's a bad idea anyway...

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/Jr79Y/35/

```
xAxis: {
            categories: ['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3']
        }
```

For the series, this is quite dirty but it works:

```
series: [{
            name: 'Test1',
            data: [20, 0, 0]
        }, {
            name: 'Test2',
            data: [0, 20, 0]
        }, {
            name: 'Test3',
            data: [0, 0, 40]
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories:['Test 1', 'Test 2', 'Test3']
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                }
                //colorByPoint: true
            },
             series: {
                colorByPoint: true
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 60,
            x: -60
        },

        series: [{
            data: [40,20,20]
        }]
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Jr79Y/36/